# How to correctly return task information when used within a Task.Run?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, asynchronous

In working with my application, I am using WCF with

> Generate task-based operations.

I would like to run the `GetAllPatientsAsync()` (defined by WCF) on a background thread. The code below works, but something feels wrong. In particular, I am losing the task information from the inner await. How is this done correctly?

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>> GetPatientList()
{
        IsLoading = true;

        var x = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
          return new ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>(await MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync());
        });

        IsLoading = false;
        return x;
}
```

Any help or suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: Just remove " await Task.Run(async () =>" stuff, why do you do that at all?

Comment: @Evk Is it not needed to return immediate control to the caller of GetPatientList() ?

Comment: No, it will be returned when you do await MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync()

Comment: @Evk If WCF should fail to connect with GetAllPatientAsync(), how can I get the task failure out of GetPatientList() to its caller???

Comment: Surround await MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync() with regular try-catch block, and handle it there. Otherwise if you call GetPatientList with await too - it will be thrown to the caller. If you don't call it with await - regular rules applied to exception inside tasks apply.

Comment: `something feels wrong... I am losing the task information` What does this mean?